# How to read from HTML input and write that data locally in a file for future access

Tags: html, c++, css, arduino-ide, esp32

I'm trying to learn ESP32. My self-given project has the following steps:

- set ESP32 as a softAP - DONE
- access ESP32 via WiFi - DONE
- serve an HTML authentication form (index1.html)(that's inside the flash memory of the ESP32) asking for a nearby Wireless Network's SSID and Password - DONE
- type the above mentioned credentials, click on a Log-In button and connect the ESP32 to that Wireless Network
- switch to a different web page (index2.html)(that's inside the flash memory of the ESP32)

Hardware:

Board:  ESP32 DEVKIT1

Core Installation version:  1.0.1-git [this one](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32#development-status)

IDE name:   Arduino IDE

Flash Frequency:    80Mhz

PSRAM enabled: no

Upload Speed:   115200

Computer OS: Linux Mint 19.1 Mate

Since I am a complete noob I've done a lot research but found nothing that I knew how to apply with my project, that's why I am writing this post.

Since I don't understand how to properly post code here (I've read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)) (code /code did not work, typing > at the beginning of each line did not work), because it will get interpreted instead of just COPY-PASTE, I made some gists. I hope they work.

#### index.html

https://gist.github.com/GeorgeFlorian/d52ed6fb10e4beaf8f64ef5edef2a78b

#### login.css

https://gist.github.com/GeorgeFlorian/8d976c512e5ddbc1a5506cc35a0326a2

#### Arduino IDE Sketch

https://gist.github.com/GeorgeFlorian/d0b6ff502675ef7599aa74d8d8aa706f

Now I would like to be able to type in SSID and Password into their respective input, click on "Sign in" button, store those in a read-only file inside the Flash Memory of the ESP32, connect the ESP32 to the respective Wireless Network and serve another web-page from inside the Flash Memory.

I didn't mention using JavaScript or PhP because I have no idea which one should be use or if they even work this way.

Also, instead of a read-only file can there may be a small database stocking only a few Wireless Networks ?

Thank you ! Sorry for the long post.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

I've never messed with the ESP32 or web services running on microcontrollers, but I mostly write web services and applications for a living.

You could use JavaScript to read the form values and submit an HTTP request to a separate endpoint to store the username and password values, but HTML [already supports forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).

The input tags you have now work with forms. All you have to do is add a form element around your inputs that specifies how to encode and transfer the form values, and what endpoint to send them to. The browser will take care of the rest when you click on the submit button:

```
<body>
    <div class="login-box">
        <form method="post" action="/login">
            <div class = "box-head">
                <div class = "logo"><img url="logo.png"></div>
                <div class = "network-title"><h1>Network Login</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class ="textbox">            
                <input type="text" placeholder="Network Name" name="networkName" value="">
            </div>        
            <div class="textbox">            
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="networkPassword" value="">
            </div>        
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Sign in">
            <input class="button" type="reset" value="Restart">        
        </form>
    </div>    
</body>
```

This would send an HTTP POST request to the `/login` endpoint with a body containing the form values encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

You don't need PHP to handle the request (and you don't have a PHP runtime to begin with). PHP executes logic on the HTTP server. In this case, the ESP32 is your HTTP server, and your logic is captured by the AsyncWebServer object inside your sketch.

[AsyncWebServerRequest can read form values](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer#get-post-and-file-parameters) for you, so all you have to do is implement the correct handler on your server:

```
server.on("/login", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
  if (!request->hasParam("networkName", true) || !request->hasParam("networkPassword", true)) {
    request->send(400, "Missing fields");
    return;
  }
  const char *networkName = request->getParam("networkName")->value().c_str();
  const char *networkPassword = request->getParam("networkPassword")->value().c_str();
  // Do stuff with networkName and networkPassword
  // ...
  // Redirect to new page
  request->redirect("/whatever");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I've been trying to make this happen but I just can't.
Here is main .cpp:
https://gist.github.com/GeorgeFlorian/7ce3de245e8a39434a5effc92d8f53a8
Here is the updated index.html:
https://gist.github.com/GeorgeFlorian/d52ed6fb10e4beaf8f64ef5edef2a78b
As you can see I've been trying to save those params in other `const *char` just to be able to `Serial.print()` them but it doesn't work.
Also, the `request->redirect("/url");` doesn't work. I've pressed on the two buttons and on enter and nothing happens.
Do you have any idea ? Because I really don't. Thank you !